# Unable to insert value in db when inside foreach() and for()

Tags: php

When a form is posted it is passed on as a `value1,value2,value3, value4`.  It has been exploded as individual values. 
Everything works well except for when I am trying to insert the `value1,value2,value3` into `$variable[$i]` it is not inserted into the table.  But when `echo $variable[$i];` it works fine.

Any idea on why the values are not inserted into the db.

```
foreach ($_POST['ECB'] as $lx) {

for($i=0;$i<=$Count;$i++) { 
        $k += mysql_num_rows($el);
    echo $variable[$i];
        mysql_select_db($database_m, $m);
        $query_stat = "Insert into table (field) values ('$variable[$i]')";
        $Result = mysql_query($query_stat, $m) or die(mysql_error());
    }

}
```

Comment: Can the person who put a -1 explain why they did so?

Comment: You should modify your statement something like this `Insert into table (field) values ('".$variable[$i]."')`

Comment: @Lion Yes did that too..

Comment: No errors, the value is not just inputted into the table.

Comment: By the way, **table** is a reserved keyword in MySql. Change your table name to something different and try it.

Comment: Excatly where does `$variable` come from? it's not defined ANYWHERE in your snippet. @lion: given the OP's also using 'field', I'm sure table/field are just anonymizations.

Comment: `table`, `$variable` are just indicative, there are values.  `echo $variable[$i]` works perfectly fine.  Values of $variable comes from outside the for loop, but inside the foreach.

Comment: What is the type of the field in the database? If it's some kind of numeric field (`INT`, `DECIMAL`, `FLOAT` etc) then remove the single quotes from your SQL query.

Comment: @lion can you put this as an answer, yes it was the int and was trying to insert varchar.  How could I have overlooked this...THANKS!

Comment: @Jean:) It's sufficient to remain it as a comment, I think. Surely glad to help you solve the problem. Thank you.

Comment: I need to close the question and provide due credit :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the type of the field in the database is some kind of numeric types (`INT`, `DECIMAL`, `FLOAT` etc) then you must remove the single quotes from your SQL query. It should look like the one shown below.

```
$query_stat = "Insert into table (field) values (".$variable[$i].")";
```